# Do we need to create new app manually in production account in GoLiveProcess of docusign?And also do we need to do all setting manually in production?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

I have successfully passed the DocuSign Go Live Process. Currently, I am in the 'Review Passed' state. I want to know what the next steps are. Do I need to create a new app in the production account? Also, do we need to configure all settings manually, or will they be automatically fetched from my developer account?

I'm not sure which plan is suitable for my client: Business Pro (eSignature) or Advanced (Developer API) account.

I want to know all about what comes after the 'Review Passed' state, such as purchasing a new production account and how to configure the DocuSign production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an eligible production account, you can promote your integration key. The integration key will get copied over to your production account. To use the integration key in production you'd need to make some changes to your application. All of these are detailed in the [After Go-live guide](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/after-go-live/)

Comment: So how can I select suitable plan for my client like there is one eSignature Buisness Pro plan another is Developer API Advanced plan which I should suggest to buy for integration. What is diffrence bwtween these ? And just for confirmation do I need to do all configuration settings manually like webhook, Brands etc .?

Comment: Your customer should probably decide on their plan based on their need, you can start with a Business Pro plan and see if the customer has what they need. You can always contact sales to get a customized plan if needed.
Webhook settings, brands, templates etc. are not being copied from the developer environment to production, you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: I believe what he's referring to are the Production plans that are eligible to promote a key to. So you're aware, all DocuSign plans do have API access, but the available API methods can be limited by what plan you're presently on.

For the purposes of Go-Live, an eligible plan is any non-trial non-freemium plan. Basically it needs an active paid subscription in order to promote the Key through the Go Live / App Review system.

The plan your customer requires depends on what it is they're doing. You may want to consider reaching out to DS Support directly to answer these questions live.

Answer (score 0):

Your customers can use any plan that includes the features that your API application uses and includes API support.

Your customers do not need to purchase an "API" plan.